# Variable undefined inside the self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder why its undefined if I declare like so:

```
var mainBtn = $('.main-button'),
    cloneFund = (function(mainBtn) {
        console.log(mainBtn); // undefined
        return arguments.callee;
    })();
```

or even:

```
var btn = $('.main-button'),
    cloneFund = (function(btn) {
        console.log(btn); // undefined
        return arguments.callee;
    })();
```

Comment: Because you aren't passing any argument into the function call, `})();`, the function parameter overwrites the variable in the outer scope, they do not share values

Comment: is it just me or the both sample are the same but just different var names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have:

```
var btn = $('.main-button'),
    cloneFund = (function(btn) {
        console.log(btn); // undefined
        return arguments.callee;
})(btn); // need to add the argument when invoked
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass mainBtn to function.

```js
var mainBtn = $('.main-button'),
    cloneFund = (function(mainBtn) {
        console.log(mainBtn); // available
        return arguments.callee;
    })(mainBtn); // here you have to pass
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="main-button">Main Button</button>
```

Comment: I see, but why doesn't the anon function have access to the variables?